# Swift 4 Decodable: How to map multiple values to a single enum value?

Tags: swift, swift4, codable, decodable

so I'm trying to use Decodable to decode a field into this format:

```
enum ClothingType: String, Decodable {
    case SHIRT
    case PANTS
    case SHOES
    case HAT
}
```

But my JSON returns the following values in the quotes, and I want them mapped to one of the four types above:

`"T_SHIRT"` and `"LONG_SLEEVE_SHIRT"` -> `SHIRT`

`"JEANS"` and `"SHORTS"` -> `PANTS`

`"SNEAKERS"` and `"SANDALS"` -> `SHOES`

`"BASEBALL_CAP"` and `"WINTER_HAT"` -> `HAT`

How do I achieve this with Decodable? Thanks!

Comment: Add your actual **JSON**

Answer (score 2):

I would instead recommend doing something like this:

```
enum ClothingType: String, Codable {
    case tShirt = "T_SHIRT"
    case longSleepShirt = "LONG_SLEEVE_SHIRT"
    case jeans = "JEANS"
    case shorts = "SHORTS"
    case sneakers = "SNEAKERS"
    case sandals = "SANDALS"
    case baseballCap = "BASEBALL_CAP"
    case winterHat = "WINTER_HAT"

    var subType: SubType {
        switch self {
        case .tShirt, .longSleepShirt:
            return .shirt
        case .jeans, .shorts:
            return .pants
        case .sneakers, .sandals:
            return .shoes
        case .baseballCap, .winterHat:
            return .hat
        }
    }

    enum SubType {
        case shirt
        case pants
        case shoes
        case hat
    }
}
```

It allows you to keep your encoded data structure true to how it will end up, while allowing you to keep naming conventions and define which aspects matter to you.

Comment: `return SubType.shirt` is redundant. `return .shirt`

Comment: Didn't realize that worked for internal enums. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

I learned this week that Decodable is really flexible, you can do something like:

```
enum ClothingType: Decodable {
    case shirt
    case pants
    case shoes
    case hat

    private enum RawClothingType: String, Decodable {
        case tShirt = "T_SHIRT"
        case longSleepShirt = "LONG_SLEEVE_SHIRT"
        case jeans = "JEANS"
        case shorts = "SHORTS"
        case sneakers = "SNEAKERS"
        case sandals = "SANDALS"
        case baseballCap = "BASEBALL_CAP"
        case winterHat = "WINTER_HAT"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let rawClothingType = try RawClothingType(from: decoder)

        switch rawClothingType {
        case .tShirt, .longSleepShirt: self = .shirt
        case .jeans, .shorts: self = .pants
        case .sneakers, .sandals: self = .shoes
        case .baseballCap, .winterHat: self = .hat
        }
    }
}
```

This hides the original clothing type (T-shirt, jeans. etc.) so use it if that's something you desire.

Comment: I like this answer. Sometime people in backend screw up and you need to fix it in the frontend